# Laravel: How can I check and get the data if the record is existing in either of the two tables?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a main table `users_mws_reimbursements` and it has a column `case_id`. What I want is to get the record/column from `users_mws_reimbursements` if the `case_id` from `users_mws_reimbursements` is existing in either of the two tables (`users_mws_case_logs` and `admin_case_info`). Is that possible?

What I tried is joining the two tables but I think it is not correct since it will check both tables.

```
 $UsersMwsReimbursements = UsersMwsReimbursements::where('users_mws_reimbursements.users_mws_id', $client->id)
     ->join('admin_case_info','admin_case_info.case_id','users_mws_reimbursements.case_id')
     ->join('users_mws_case_logs','users_mws_case_logs.case_id','users_mws_reimbursements.case_id')
     ->whereDate('users_mws_reimbursements.approval_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))
     ->get();

dd($UsersMwsReimbursements);
```

NOTE: `UsersMwsReimbursements` model is  `users_mws_reimbursements`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) has  [`whereExists`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereExists) and [`orWhereExists`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereExists) methods which might be what you are looking for.

Something like the following:

```
UsersMwsReimbursements::whereDate('users_mws_reimbursements.approval_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))
    ->whereExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('users_mws_case_logs')
            ->whereColumn('users_mws_case_logs.case_id', 'users_mws_reimbursements.case_id');
    })->orWhereExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('admin_case_info')
            ->whereColumn('admin_case_info.case_id', 'users_mws_reimbursements.case_id');
    });
```

Comment: can i use `orWhereExists` in both sir?

Comment: @draw134 If that is what you need, yes.